# Fixing an infinite loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, numbers, infinite-loop

I am a first year Comp Sci major and in class we have a project where we make the algorithm for the game called "Bagels." We are to make a random 3 digit number, but none of the digits can be the same number. So numbers like "100, 220, 343, and 522" would be illegal because they contain digits that have the same number.

I decided it would be best to generate each digit separately, compare each digit and change if needed, and add each digit into a string. Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Generate a random 3 digit number between 102 and 987. The bounds are 102 to 987 because each 
    // digit in the number must be different. The generated number will be called SecretNum and be
    // stored as a String.

    // The First digit is generated between 1 and 9 while the second and third digit are generated 
    // between 0 and 9.

    String SecretNum = "";
    int firstDigit = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    int secondDigit = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int thirdDigit = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

    // Now the program checks to see if any of the digits share the same value and if one digit shares 
    // the same value then the number is generated repeatedly until the value is different

    // Digit tests are used to determine whether or not any of the digits share the same value.
    boolean firstDigitTest = (firstDigit == secondDigit) || (firstDigit == thirdDigit);

    boolean secondDigitTest = (secondDigit == firstDigit) || (secondDigit == thirdDigit);

    boolean thirdDigitTest = (thirdDigit == firstDigit) || (thirdDigit == secondDigit);

    if (firstDigitTest){
        do{
            firstDigit = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        }while (firstDigitTest);

    } else if (secondDigitTest){
        do{
            secondDigit = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        }while(secondDigitTest);

    } else if (thirdDigitTest){
        do{
            thirdDigit = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        }while(thirdDigitTest);
    }// end if statements

    // Now the program will place each digit into their respective places
    SecretNum = firstDigit + "" + secondDigit + "" + thirdDigit;

    System.out.println(SecretNum);
```

(Ignore the scanner for now; it's unnecessary for this part, but I'll need it later)

Unfortunately, when I'm testing the digits to see whether there any that are the same number I sometimes will be stuck in an infinite loop. The tricky part is that sometimes it will run like it's an infinite loop, but then generate the number before I terminate the program. So sometimes if it's in an infinite loop I'm unsure if it's really in an infinite loop or I am being impatient, but I'm sure it's an infinite loop problem because I waited for around 10 minutes and the program was still running.

I'm really not sure why it becomes an infinite loop because if it happens that one digit matches another then the digit should be continuously generated until it is a different number so I don't understand how it's even becoming an infinite loop. This is where I need help.

(Oh and how I am making the String is not how I will keep it. Once I get this loop fixed I'll change it so that the digits are appended to the string.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that (for example) `firstDigitTest` is set to a specific Boolean value, either `true` or `false`, and never changed. Even after you set `firstDigit` to a different value, thereby resolving the problem that `firstDigitTest` detected, you don't re-update `firstDigitTest` to detect if the problem is still there. So each of your loops, if it's entered at all, will loop indefinitely.

I think you might as well just eliminate your Boolean variables, and loop `while(firstDigit == secondDigit || firstDigit == thirdDigit || secondDigit == thirdDigit)`.

Comment: @DonRoby: The other answerer to this question lost 1 rep-point at about the same time that my answer was downvoted, so I believe (s)he is the one who downvoted it. You can see his/her answer to see what (s)he believes the correct answer is, and therefore why (s)he downvoted mine. **Update:** Now (s)he's deleted his/her answer and undownvoted mine, so I guess everyone is in agreement now. :-)

Comment: Lol, interesting community. Anyways, thanks for the answer; it worked perfectly! I felt pretty dumb once I read what you posted, but then again I am a freshman. Haha

Comment: @StephonGordon: You're welcome! You may be interested to know that there are actually some languages where it's possible for a variable denote an expression, with its value potentially being different each time you reference it. (This happens, for example, in "call-by-name" semantics, which you can Google for if you're curious.) One of the really cool things about programming is that there are many different possible abstractions, and different languages take different approaches -- but, as you've found, abstraction "mismatches" can make for confusing bugs!